# Promise chaining not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, promise

I have following code to select multiple contacts and the filter only names that have XYZ. I am using then and done to accomplish this filter. In my contacts, there is one contact named **XYZ Dude** and I am selecting it also. Shouldn't this contact be passed in my done method after the filtering logic I apply in the then method? Any ideas what I may be doing wrong here

```
var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();

        // Open the picker for the user to select a contact.
        picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts) {
            var contactsStartingWithPrefixPa = contacts.filter(function filterContacts(contact) {
                if (contact.name.match(/XYZ/))
                    return true;
                return false;
            });
        }).done(function (contacts) {
            // code never reaches here
            if (contacts != null ) {
                contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                    if (contact !== null) {
                        // logic to use this contact

                    }
                }
            )}
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return contactsStartingWithPrefixPa` is required in the then function.

```
   // Open the picker for the user to select a contact.
    picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts) {
        var contactsStartingWithPrefixPa = contacts.filter(function filterContacts(contact) {
            if (contact.name.match(/XYZ/))
                return true;
            return false;
        return contactsStartingWithPrefixPa;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a good reason to separate the filter from the "logic to use this contact", then both can be performed in one looping operation.

```
var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();

// Open the picker for the user to select a contact.
picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().done(function(contacts) {
    if(contacts) {
        contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
            if(contact.name.match(/XYZ/)) {
                // logic to use this contact
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you're looping through `contacts` with `.filter()` then looping again with `.forEach()`.

If you really must separate two aspects, then (assuming `contacts` has a `.filter()` method) you should be able to do so as follows :

```
var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();

// Open the picker for the user to select a contact.
picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function(contacts) {
    return contacts ? contacts.filter(function(contact) {
        return !!contact.name.match(/XYZ/);
    }) : [];
}).done(function(contacts) {
    contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
        // logic to use this contact
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value from contacts.filter is not a promise, so you don't need to do any additional chaining here. Your code should look like this, as contactsStartingWithPrefixPa is simply a projection of contacts, so you can just do a forEach iteration directly:

```
        picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().done(function (contacts) {
        var contactsStartingWithPrefixPa = contacts.filter(function filterContacts(contact) {
            if (contact.name.match(/XYZ/))
                return true;
            return false;
        })

        if (contactsStartingWithPrefixPa.length > 0) {
            contactsStartingWithPrefixPa.forEach(function (contact) {
                //Process
            });
        }
    });
```

Chaining of promises only works when each step of the chain (except the last) returns a new promise. If there isn't a promise to return, you don't have another async step so you can just process what you need right ther

Comment: If a callback function on a promise returns a non-promise, it's automatically wrapped in a promise for that value by the infrastructure. So it's not strictly true that you have to have another promise in order to do chaining. You should return something, though, otherwise you get a promise for undefined.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, Chris. Another promise is always needed, ultimately, but the fact that a non-promise will be automatically wrapped is helpful to know.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that either, it sounds like it could produce some weird results if you're not expecting it. Rather than simply returning `myObj` and letting it get wrapped automagically, it might be clearer explicitly to return `WinJS.Promise.as( myObj )`.